# Is it possible to have the parent entity affect each of its child entity differently?

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to recreate a solar system in VR. I was able to recreate revolution by setting up each planets as the child entity of the sun, and then using the animation function to rotate the sun. However, I would like to make it more realistic by having each planet revolve around the sun at different rates. How would this be done without actively writing out a separate javascript file for the animation? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make planets children of the sun. Use an entity as center of the solar system and rotate each planet around a pivot. You can apply different animations to different planets:

```
<a-entity id="earthPivot"
  animation="property: rotation; easing: linear; to: 0 360 0; dur: 5000; loop: true;">
  <a-sphere id="earth" position="0 0 -3.2" radius="0.5" color="blue"></a-sphere>
</a-entity>
```

[Full example on glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jewel-valiant-locket?path=index.html%3A24%3A19)